# loadOptions getting called for same string which was searched earlier and cacheOptions is enabled

Tags: react-select, loadoptions

I am trying to use `AsyncSelect` from `react-select` library.

I have enabled `cacheOptions` option.

Using below mentioned steps I am seeing an issue with `loadOptions`

1. Search for a string `test`
2. List of options gets displayed
3. `Clear` the input field
4. Enter `same string` again `test`
5. Immediately displays `same list of options`
6. `loadOptions` fires an API with search input `tes`
7. `Clear` the input field
8. Enter `same string` again `test`
9. Immediately displays `same list of options`
10. loadOptions fires API with search input `te`.

I am not sure why loadOptions getting fired in this scenario if I am entering the same search string.

Here is the `AsyncSelect`

```
<AsyncSelect
  classNamePrefix="select-item"
  onChange={ onOptionSelect }
  getOptionValue={ item => item.id }
  placeholder="Search by Item"
  formatOptionLabel={ company => <CompanyWithIcon Item={ Item } /> }
  loadOptions={ loadOptions }
  styles={ customStyles }
  isSearchable
  cacheOptions
  isClearable
/>
```

Here is the `loadOptions` function

```
const loadOptions = inputValue => searchItem(inputValue);
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you are not using a callback or a promise for loadOptions. The loadOptions should return a promise.

Reference doc -> https://react-select.com/props#async-props says:

loadOptions:
Function that returns a promise, which is the set of options to be used once the promise resolves.

It should be like below:

```
const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(searchItem(inputValue));
  }, 1000);
};
```